Emacs storing unwanted file changes
I have the following in my Emacs config file:
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.emacs-saves/")))
(setq backup-by-copying t)

On my home computer using an up-to-date Emacs on up-to-date Ubuntu (I'm not sure of the exact version number, I'm not there now) this works as expected.
Using the same config on my work machine (Emacs 29.3 on Ubuntu Linux) has a peculiarity where I'll type some unwanted text, exit with :q! (Evil user), and then when I reopen the file the unwanted text is still there. There is no Autosave file nor Backup file in either the directory in which the original file is found, nor in ~/.emacs-saves/ (ls -a). There are no relevant lines in the Messages or Scratch buffers.
Where might this data be stored, and how can I prevent it from occurring?

Please try reducing this to the minimal config. I understand that same config has problem on one machine and doesn't on another, but that doesn't change that if the problem is always reproducible, it is possible to reduce it to the minimal configuration to debug then from there. Applying divide&conquer algorithm to test/reduce 2000 lines configuration takes just ≈11 steps, so I presume it shouldn't take too long.

Will do, thank you. I'll be back in the office on Sunday and update.
